# How to describe a system with stability in terms of some variables

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Assume I have a system:

$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}L(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) \\ \dot{\mathbf{y}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{y}}L(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$

where $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $L$ is Lipchitz continuous. The equilibria are $(\mathbf{x}^*,\mathbf{y})$ for any $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and isolated in terms of $\mathbf{x}^*$. That is, for each $\mathbf{x}^*$ and any $\mathbf{y}$, $(\mathbf{x}^*,\mathbf{y})$ is an equilibrium, and for a small neighbourhood $\mathbb{B}_{\mathbf{x}^*}-\{\mathbf{x}^*\}$ around $\mathbf{x}^*$, there does not exist another $\mathbf{x}'$ such that $(\mathbf{x}',\mathbf{y})$ is equilibrium. I can further show that at equilibrium, $\ddot{\mathbf{x}}$ is negative definite, $\ddot{\mathbf{y}}=\mathbf{0}$, $\frac{\partial^2 L(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})}{\partial\mathbf{x}\partial\mathbf{y}}=\mathbf{0}$, $\frac{\partial^2 L(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})}{\partial\mathbf{y}\partial\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{0}$.

I am wondering if I can say this system is asymptotically stable. If not, what should I do to discribe its stability?

Please share your advice. Many thanks.

Comment: Has the function $L(x,y)$ any other properties? If $L$ is lower bounded,  I think that it may be possible to prove convergence to an equilibrium. Also, when you say that $\ddot{x}$ is negative definite, do you mean that the matrix $\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x^2}$ is negative definite?

Comment: @RTJ Thanks very much for your reply. $L$ is indeed lower bounded and $\ddot{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial\mathbf{x}^2}$. I have found that Theorem A.4 in the paper ["Gradient descent GAN optimization is locally stable"](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7142-gradient-descent-gan-optimization-is-locally-stable) may help me.